# Verify that option is visible inside select with multiple attribute using Selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have select element

```html
<select id = "country" align="left" name="SelectValue" style="width:300px" size="5" multiple=""><option value="...">...</option><option value="Argentina">Argentina</option><option value="Austria">Austria</option><option value="Belgium">Belgium</option><option value="Brazil">Brazil</option><option value="Canada">Canada</option><option value="Denmark">Denmark</option><option value="Finland">Finland</option><option value="France">France</option><option value="Germany">Germany</option><option value="Ireland">Ireland</option><option value="Italy">Italy</option><option value="Mexico">Mexico</option><option value="Norway">Norway</option><option value="Poland">Poland</option><option value="Portugal">Portugal</option><option value="Spain">Spain</option><option value="Sweden">Sweden</option><option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option><option value="UK">UK</option><option value="USA">USA</option><option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option></select>
```

I need to verify if it allows scrolling after some option has been chosen. Example: I choose Argentina, then I scroll to the bottom of the select and see Venezuela.
I found out how to scroll particular element. The problem is when I check "Displayed" property of an option, it is always true; even if it is located at the bottom of a list and scroll bar at the top.

```
IWebElement country = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("country"));
var select = new SelectElement(country);
IWebElement option = select.Options.First(op => op.Text == "Venezuela");
((IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];", select, 500);
return option.Displayed;
```

Comment: Of course it will return displayed. Every option is displayed. Like when you check for an element on the page that is further down (and you have to scroll to see it), it is displayed, you just don't see it because you need to scroll. Just like that in select element, every option is displayed.
For the element not to be displayed, it must not appear no matter how much you scroll.

Can you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve, and maybe we can work this out?

Comment: I have a test case which was discovered during manual testing. A list is unscrollable after a user chooses an option.
So in order to reproduce it and confirm that everything works,  I decide to perform following steps:
1) Choose the first option.
2) Scroll down.
3) Check that last option is visible to the user.

Comment: If choosing your last option does not ruin your scenario, why don't you do this:
1) Choose the first option
2) Verify that the .SelectedOption is the first one
3) Choose the last option
4) Verify that the .SelectedOption is the last one

With this, you can verify that the first/last option does not "lock" the dropdown.